# JSP Form Not Connecting with Servlet 404-Error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I'm having a little issue connecting with my servlet so that I can pass some data to a mysql database.  I've read a bunch of the threads here, but have had no luck with suggestions to other members.

I have a jsp page named "insertData.jsp"  On that page there is a form where the action points to a servlet named "UpdateData".  When I click submit on the web page, I get a 404 error stating that the requested resource is not available.  I have also updated my web xml file to try to point to the right direction.

So here's my folder setup:
The UpdateData.java is in the controller package of the source packages folder.  The name of the project is "RukertContainerTracker".

Here's my jsp page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert Data</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Insert Data Into Container Records</h1>

        <H1>The Rukert Terminals Container Tracker </H1>

        <form name="Insert Record" action="/UpdateData" method="Post">

            Container Number: <input type="text" name="containerNumber"> <br /> 
            Full Out: <input type="date" name="fullOut" /> <br/>
            Empty In: <input type="date" name="emptyIn" /> <br/>
            Empty Out <input type="date" name="emptyOut" /> <br/>
            Full In: <input type="date" name="fullIn" /> <br/>
            Comments: <input type="text" name="comments" /> <br/>           
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />        

        </form>


               <div>
            <a href="javascript:history.back();">
            <span class="categoryLabelText">HOME</span>
        </a>

        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

My servlet:

```
    package controller;

import java.io.IOException; 
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse; 

public class UpdateData extends HttpServlet {    
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse     response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException { 

       //Get container data from the JSP page 

        String container=request.getParameter("containerNumber"); 
        String fullOutDate=request.getParameter("fullOut"); 
        String emptyInDate=request.getParameter("emptyIn");
        String emptyOutDate=request.getParameter("emptyOut");
        String fullInDate=request.getParameter("fullIn");
        String comments=request.getParameter("comments");

        //Print the above got values in console 

        System.out.println("The username is" +container); 
        System.out.println("\nand the password is" +fullOutDate);

        String connectionparams="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rukerttracker";
        String db="rukerttracker";

        String uname="root";
        String psword="Colorado1982";

        Connection connection=null;

        ResultSet rs; 
        try { 

          // Loading the available driver for a Database communication 

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

//Creating a connection to the required database 

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection 
             (connectionparams, uname, psword); 

       //Add the data into the database 

            String sql = "insert into containerinventory values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            try (PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
                prep.setString(1, container);
                prep.setString(2, fullOutDate);
                prep.setString(3, emptyInDate);
                prep.setString(4, emptyOutDate);
                prep.setString(5, fullInDate);
                prep.setString(6, comments);

                prep.executeUpdate();
            } 

           }catch(Exception E){

               System.out.println("The error is=="+E.getMessage()); 


           }


finally{
            connection.close();
        }


    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

        String userPath = request.getServletPath();

        // if category page is requested
        if (userPath.equals("/insertData")) {
            // TODO: Implement category request


            // use RequestDispatcher to forward request internally
        String url = "/WEB-INF/view" + userPath + ".jsp";

        try {
            request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

And finally my web.xml page:

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/chooseLanguage</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/viewTracker</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/editTracker</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/addToCart</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/viewCompany</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/category</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/updateCart</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/purchase</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/viewCart</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/checkout</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>UpdateData</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.UpdateData</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>UpdateData</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/insertData</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I have two servlets, I don't know if this matters, but I couldn't get the application to work in the controller servlet, so I created the Update Data servlet.

Any help as to why I keep getting this 404 error would be greatly, greatly appreciated.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 1):

I think in form you are using POST method and your servlet does not have post method. please check it.
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{...}
not available.

Comment: Subhash, thanks for your insight. Should I just add an empty POST method to the servlet or put all of my code from the processRequest call in the servlet to the newly created POST method? Any additional thoughts you could share would be great. Basically what I'm trying to do, as you can probably see, is get the data passed from form to servlet to mysql database (I'm trying to input into the db).

Comment: call your processRequest method from doPost like  void processRequest(request,response)

Comment: Subhash, you've been really helpful.  Just a little confusion on my end, would you mind just giving me a snippet of code that I should try?  From what I'm reading it looks like you're suggesting that I do something like: protected void doPost(request, response)....should I use those exact words in the mehtod (request, response)?  Sorry if I'm being a pain, I really want to learn this stuff.  Thanks again for your time and patience.

Comment: Also, where should I add the new code?  To the bottom of my servlet, or top?  Does it matter?  Thanks again.